# Google Cloud Platform projects sharing snapshots

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snapshot

I have a snapshot on one Google Cloud Platform account and I want to share the same snapshot with another account in different project.

Can someone help with what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Complete guide is available in  Google Cloud [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects)

Answer (score 0):

You can use snapshot from one project to create a disk in another project

> Create a snapshot of disk-1:

> gcloud compute disks snapshot disk-1 --project project-a --snapshot-names snapshot-1

> Create a new disk in project-b that is based on the snapshot:

> gcloud compute disks create disk-2  --project project-b --source-snapshot  projects/project-a/global/snapshots/snapshot-1

> Attach the new disk to the instance instance-1 in project-b.

> gcloud compute instances attach-disk instance-1 --project project-b --disk disk-2

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#sharing_snapshots